# Sed Issue - Bad flag in substitute command: '#'

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I am running a script in mac that was inherited by my team and it has some replacement code which doesnt seem to be running properly. I tried a variety of subsitute characters like %,\ etc but nothing seems to be working. Can someone give me an idea of what else should I change.

The script is run like this

```
./test.sh /Users/Apple/Test_Folder/ 425323 C6C7CB 425363 425363 425363 666666 666666 425363 425363 666666 425363 425363 a0a9b1 687582 a0a9b2
```

The issue inside the script(test.sh) is this **for loop**

```
for f in "$1"/*.svg;
do
  sed -i '' 's\#000002\#'"$2"'/g;s\#000003\#'"$3"'/g;s\#000004\#'"$4"'/g;s\#000005\#'"$5"'/g;s\#000006\#'"$6"'/g;s\#000007\#'"$7"'/g;s\#000008\#'"$8"'/g;s\#000009\#'"$9"'/g;s\#000010\#'"$10"'/g;s\#000011\#'"$11"'/g;s\#000012\#'"$12"'/g;s\#000013\#'"$13"'/g;s\#000014\#'"$14"'/g;s\#000015\#'"$15"'/g;s\#000016\#'"$16"'/g' $f
done
```

The error i get is 
sed: 1: "s%#000002%#425323/g;s%# ...": bad flag in substitute command: '#'

Any pointers?

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: Welcome to SO, please wrap up your samples in CODE TAGS a `{}` button and edit your post. Let us know then.

Comment: The command should look like `s/pattern/replacement/` or `s#pattern#replacement#`, but yours is `s#pattern#replacement/`. You don't have to escape the delimiter in the `s` command (unless it's part of the pattern or the replacement, of course, which it isn't in your case).

Comment: Edited per your comment RavinderSingh13

Comment: I get `substitute pattern can not be delimited by newline or backslash`

Comment: Benjamin,  I even tried what you had mentioned. I got the same error sed: 1: "s#000002#425323/g;s#000 ...": bad flag in substitute command: '0'...Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, you're still using `s##/` instead of `s///` or `s###`.

Comment: Specifically: `"s/000002/$2/g"` or `"s#000002#$2#g"` should both work. You can also avoid some quoting ugliness by just double quoting the whole command.

Comment: You are mixing delimiters, you have `s#  #  /g` instead of `s# # #g` or `s/ / /g` (I know that was said by @BenjaminW., but you don't seem to understand).

Answer (score 1):

Reformat so it's easier to read, find, and edit.
Use double-quotes as script delimiters so you don't need so many workarounds.

```
for f in "$1"/*.svg;
do
  sed -i "
    s/#000002/#$2/g;
    s/#000003/#$3/g;
    s/#000004/#$4/g;
    s/#000005/#$5/g;
    s/#000006/#$6/g;
    s/#000007/#$7/g;
    s/#000008/#$8/g;
    s/#000009/#$9/g;
    s/#000010/#$10/g;
    s/#000011/#$11/g;
    s/#000012/#$12/g;
    s/#000013/#$13/g;
    s/#000014/#$14/g;
    s/#000015/#$15/g;
    s/#000016/#$16/g;
  " $f
done
```

If you're *comfortable* with heavy abstraction you can try something like this, but make sure you test it heavily...

```
for s in $(seq 2 16)
do  n="$(printf "%06d" $s)"
    script="$script s/#$n/#\${$s}/g; "
done
for f in "$1"/*.svg;
do  eval " sed -i \" $script \" \"$f\" "
done
```

Comment: I think OP wanted to use `#` as a delimiter, not part of the search and replacement string; but it's not 100% clear from the question.

Comment: Also, you don't need the semicolons any longer, and you should quote `$f` after your command.

Comment: Then, I think from `$10` on, you need to write it `${10}`.

Comment: Likely would help in some circumstances - certainly wouldn't hurt. I don't think it's needed with this particular dataset, but I updated. As for the delimiter, I made some guesses based on the existing script, assuming the point was to sub in a set of numbers fro the placeholders listed as arguments 2-16. If you just assume someone put in the wrong slash, it makes sense. I figured in the least someone might get a useful idea from it.

Comment: @BenjaminW. .. in what scenario do you not require semicolons between substitute commands in the same execution block? `echo test | sed 's/t/T/ s/e/E/'` doesn't work....

Comment: @ghoti I was referring to the first code block. If you have the commands on a single line, you're of course right, the semicolons are required.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks for the clarification. :)

Comment: Unnecessary with newlines, but they don't hurt. Some folk just like 'em for the consistency and added clarity. Some dislike for the fact that they are extraneous clutter. Either is ok, I think, as long as you make your choice for a reason, and it works.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help..Spl thanks to Benjamin